# How to share timeline item from Google+ glassware which have two options (Comment, +1), no Share?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Current Google+ glassware adds a timeline item with shared picture when picture is shared to this user(device). Now this timeline item  have two options (comment, +1), from this timeline item, is it possible to share this picture to some other glassware app, 
or is it my glassware app should implement same functionality as Google+ glassware does.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to share Google+ timeline item unless the Google+ Glassware adds the `SHARE` menu item to the timeline items it inserts.

Please start this discussion in the Glass community forum and/or contact your guide to ask for this feature to be implemented; make sure to add as much details as possible regarding your use-case.